# Submitting a form from Email

Tags: html, email

I was working on a project to submit a form from an email. The scenario is this. We will send a form to list of emails where in the customer has to fill in the form and once they hit submit, the form should be submitted and server should be able to retrieve the values that is provided by the person filling in.When i tried, it was not considering the submit button as form submit and no action is being performed. Can anyone help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you writing this in?  Do you have code to demonstrate your problem?  Not much we can do to help without more information.

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle here. A lot of email clients will severely restrict what markup you can include in an HTML email to the point where a lot of functionality is impossible. GMail, Yahoo! Mail and Hotmail are especially challenging. I recommend hosting the form on a web server and proving a link from the email. You're wasting your time trying to get a form to work from an email.

Comment: The most impressive case is the new Outlook. Totally deleting the text input / textarea and button.

Answer (score 10):

HTML forms and client side code are typically restricted from most email clients. This is an obvious attack vector and as such your abilities are limited when dealing with HTML based email.

I would recommend providing a link to a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a Form through Email is possible, 
The code i wrote to send Email(using PHP SwiftMailer),

```
//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, "ssl") 
  ->setUsername('my_id@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('*****')
  ;
//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
//Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Fill the form')
  ->setFrom(array('me@gmail.com' => 'Harry'))
  ->setTo(array('some_mail1@gmail.com','some_mail2@gmail.com'))
  ->setBody('<html>' .
            ' <head></head>' .
            ' <body>'.
            ' <form action="http://www.our_domail.com/index.php" method="get">'.
            ' <label>Name: </label><input type="input" id="name"  name="name"/><br/>' .
            ' <label>phone: </label><input type="input" id="phone" name="phone" /><br/>'.
            ' <label>About you: </label><br/>'.
            ' <textarea id="about" name="textb"></textarea> <input type="submit" value="submit" />'.
            ' </form>'.
            ' </body>' .
            '</html>',
            'text/html')
  ;
  //Send the message
  if ($mailer->send($message))
  {
    echo "Sent\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Failed\n";
  }
```

In the Mail Box i got the form, which on submitting shows some messages like `You are submitting information to an external page.
Are you sure?` and `Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered   is     to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.
Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?`

On clicking on Continue, it gets posted to my server with data in the form. i am not sure about that we can use javascript validations or css stylesheets in our forms.
Note: `This was tested in Gmail server and i don't know about other mail servers.`.

Actually this worked for me, hope it helped you too..

Comment: Apparently wont work in outlook: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/

Comment: There are quite a few email clients which don't support HTML forms.