# sending feedback form through email

Tags: php, html, email

I want to send a user feedback form through email. when they press submit button form should go to the mentioned id.
How to achieve this? is it possible?

Comment: I would say it's dangerous. And what `ID` you are talking about?

Comment: what do you mean with "mentioned id"? make your question more understandable please

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402749/submitting-a-form-from-email

Comment: Its possible, but personally i'd do it in asp, find it easier than php.

Comment: @ Arsen and max4ever, mentioned id means email id which is mentioned in the sending mail. 
What exactly i am looking is: We will send a form to our customers and customer will fill & Submit this form.

@Aaron Lee, i do not know much about asp. can you please let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of going about this would be to create some kind of contact form, on your actually site, just don't have the direct URL visible to everyone, then rather than sending the actual form to a client/customer/whatever, just send them the link to the form and allow them to fill it in on the site and submit it, if you do it in php then the email can be sent directly to you personally.

This will talk you through creating the form:
http://php.about.com/od/phpapplications/ss/form_mail.htm

You may also want to research validation to other any nasty suprises through hackers or injections, and try to make it as secure as possible.

Hope this helps.