# Form submit button embeded in gmail doesnt work

Tags: html, email, gmail

I want to embed a form in my mail content so that the reader can fill it and submit it. its working in Thunderbird mail client. However in case of gmail, clicking on submit button does nothing. Is gmail deliberately doing this? Can I use javascript to overcome this?

Comment: Script will not work, check this one to see if you do it in the same way: https://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting a form from Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402749/submitting-a-form-from-email)

Comment: Thanks to the example in the link you had shared, I got the clue. The trick is to use target="_blank" in the form tag so that Gmail prompts you to open it in new window. It shows a warning but that is ok.